# How to replicate this function in R many times?

Tags: r

I need to replicate the following function many times using different elements. I am very new to R and the only way I know how to is with copy-paste.
I need to calculate the proportion that each program represents in its area excluding the "Undecided" of the area. And I need proportions of each area stored in a separate list or vector for further calculations.

```
df2 = data.frame (area=rep(c("Eng", "Hum"),each=3), program=c("Chem", "Mech", "Undecided","Hist", "Law", "Undecided"))
df2
  area   program
1  Eng      Chem
2  Eng      Mech
3  Eng Undecided
4  Hum      Hist
5  Hum       Law
6  Hum Undecided
p.Mech = sum(program=="Mech" & area=="Eng") / (sum(area=="Eng")- sum(program=="Undecided" & area=="Eng"))
p.Chem = sum(program=="Chem" & area=="Eng") / (sum(area=="Eng")- sum(program=="Undecided" & area=="Eng"))
p.Hist = sum(program=="Hist" & area=="Hum") / (sum(area=="Hum")- sum(program=="Undecided" & area=="Hum"))
p.law = sum(program=="Law" & area=="Hum") / (sum(area=="Hum")- sum(program=="Undecided" & area=="Hum"))
```

In my real data I have 9 areas and about 5 programs for each area.
This is my first post ever on stack.exchange so sorry if the question is too dumb or doesn't belong here. Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just do the following. Remove undecided entries, tally up the results by program and area, and calculate proportions by area.

```r
df2= data.frame (area=rep(c("Eng", "Hum"),each=3), program=c("Chem", "Mech", "Undecided","Hist", "Law", "Undecided"))

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)  # just converting to a data.table
dt2 %>%
  .[program != "Undecided"] %>%
  .[, .N, keyby = .(area, program)] %>%
  .[, P := N / sum(N), keyby = "area"] %>%
  .[]  # just for displaying
#>    area program N   P
#> 1:  Eng    Chem 1 0.5
#> 2:  Eng    Mech 1 0.5
#> 3:  Hum    Hist 1 0.5
#> 4:  Hum     Law 1 0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! But how can I use the proportions for further calculations?
Say, I want to create sample of a 100 Eng students, which in this case will consist of 50 Chem and 50 Mech.